# FFT of a periodic function

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

Suppose you have N samples of a sine wave of frequency $f_0$ sampled at $f_s$.

$$
x[n] = A\sin[2\pi(f_0 /f_s)n]
$$

1. How do you get a delta function in the frequency domain (i.e. all of the energy is in the center one bin of the FFT)?
2. Does the number of samples (N) need to be a prime number of cycles of $f_0$? If so, why?
3. Does $f_s$ need to be an integer multiple of $f_0$? If so, why?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/m-point-fft-amplitude-of-n-samples-of-a-sinusoid)

Comment: Not sure, but I think you're mixing up the FFT (a fast implementation) and the FT (the mathematical transform that is being implemented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to look at exponentials. The reasoning is exactly the same, but if a sine or cosine were used, we would need two exponentials. So first let's say that $$x[n]=e^{j2\pi\frac{f_0}{fs}n} $$
Then the DFT is $$\begin{align}
X_N[k]&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}e^{j2\pi\frac{f_0}{fs}n} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j2\pi n\left ( \frac{k}{N}-\frac{f_0}{f_s} \right)} \\
&=\frac{1-e^{-j2\pi N\left(\frac{k}{N} -\frac{f_0}{f_s}\right)}}{1-e^{-j2\pi \left(\frac{k}{N} -\frac{f_0}{f_s}\right)}} \mbox{, where } k=0,\ldots,N-1
\end{align}$$

For this to be a delta, we need the following condition to be satisfied:
$$
N\left(\frac{k}{N}-\frac{f_0}{f_s}\right) \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow k-N\frac{f_0}{f_s} \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

With this condition, the numerator is always zero. The denominator will be zero if $$ \frac{k}{N}-\left.\frac{f_0}{f_s}\right\vert_{k=k_0}=0 \mbox{, or } k_0=N\frac{f_0}{f_s}$$

At that particular $k_0$, you will need to use L'Hospital's Rule.
This will give you the complete DFT as $$X_N[k]=\begin{cases} N &\mbox{ if } k=N\frac{f_0}{f_s} \\ 0 &\mbox { else} \end{cases} \mbox{, } k=0,\ldots,N-1$$

So what conditions did we impose to get this result? Just that $k-N\frac{f_0}{f_s} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $k$ is already an integer, we need only check $N\frac{f_0}{f_s}$. Define $f_s=af_0$. Therefore $a$ is the number of points in a cycle. Then we need $$\frac{N}{a} \in \mathbb{Z}$$
This can only be satisfied if $a$ is an integer, and $N$ is an integer multiple of $a$.

Putting all this together, if the sampling frequency is an integer multiple of the input's frequency, and $N$ is an integer number of points in a cycle of the sampled exponential, then the DFT of $x[n]$ will be a delta with height $N$.

Comment: There is no need to use L'Hospital's rule. When $k_0 = N\frac{f_0}{f_s}$, we have that $$X[k_0] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j2\pi n\left ( \frac{k_0}{N}-\frac{f_0}{f_s} \right)} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^0 = N,$$ no muss, no fuss, and no need to disturb the poor Marquis's ghost.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. I generally do L'Hospital's, just because it's easy for the exponentials, but your way is very clear.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that we're talking about a Kronecker-like delta, not a Dirac-delta.

Answer (score 0):

In reverse order,

1. Yes the sampling frequency needs to be a multiple of $f_0$.
2. The number of *cycles* of the sinusoid in $N$ samples needs to be an
   integer, not necessarily a prime number.
3. If you do 3. and 2., all the energy will be concentrated in two bins
   (corresponding to $100$ Hz and $-100$ Hz.

Be careful, though. If you have a sinusoid $x(t)=\sin(2\pi (100) t)$ at 100 Hz
and you sample it at 1000 Hz, you will have $10$ samples per cycle of the
waveform. With $x[0] = 0$ and $x[9] \neq 0$, you can do an "FFT"
of length $10$ if you like, and all the energy will be in $X[1]$ and $X[9]$.
I put FFT in quotation marks because at such short lengths, a plain
vanilla brute-force DFT calculation might be almost as fast. Note also
that $x[10] = 0$ is **not** part of the DFT calculation.
Alternatively, you can use $N = 10n$ samples and do an FFT of length $1000$  (say) on samples $x[0]$ through $x[999]$.  In this case, the 
energy will all be in $X[10]$ and $X[1014]$.
Regardless of what some other answers will likely tell you,

> DO NOT zero-pad the length $1000$ FFT to length $1024$ to get an
>   "efficient" implementation.

If you do follow the advice on zero-padding, your length-$1024$ FFT
will NOT have the energy concentrated in two bins as you desire.

Comment: But why does $f_s$ need to be a multiple of $f_0$?

Comment: @Seth $f_s$ needs to be a multiple of $f_0$ because you need one full period of the sinusoid (from $0$ at $t = 0$ to $0$ at $t = 1/f_0$) to be an integer number of samples. Else, the energy of the sinusoid will be smeared over several bins.

Answer (score 0):

For any length of FFT and sample rate Fs, you can calculate the entire set of (positive) frequencies for which a pure sinusoid will produce a delta function in the FFT result.  They are:

```
k * Fs / FFTLength
```

for integer k = 0 to infinity.  (Or to FFTLength/2 if you don't want aliases.)

Any other frequency sinusoid will not produce a delta, but instead a sampled periodic Sinc or Dirichlet function (conjugate mirrored for strictly real input).  So you can answer your own 3 questions by process of elimination.